# Is there a good DI framework suitable for Java 1.4 and SE (Swing) apps?

Tags: java, swing, spring, dependency-injection

I am looking for a dependency injection framework for a Java SE (Swing) application that runs under JDK 1.4. Are there any recommended DI frameworks that I can use? (Guice and other annotation-based frameworks are out, and I don't want to mess with something like Retroweaver.)

Also, is Spring suitable for use in a Java SE application?

edit: this is a legacy application (which is why it's jdk 1.4) - I want to use spring to get some sanity into the ball of mud

Comment: You can introduce a DI framework like Spring into your app, but you can't move up from Java 1.4 (end-of-lifed by SUN, by the way)?

With any significant code base it would be a lot of work to retrofit a DI framework.  Are the potential benefits worth the cost?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm exploring. It wouldn't require a total retrofit, would it? Couldn't I just start by injecting a few dependencies at a time?

There are some significant technical barriers (deployment issues) that are keeping the app on 1.4.

Comment: @hbunny, for some mainframe installations you get 1.4 only, and it is very tedious to have any other versions installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is. There is even a whole project called [Spring Rich Client](http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/index.html):

> Spring-RCP's mission is to provide an elegant way to build highly-configurable, GUI-standards-following rich-client applications faster by leveraging the Spring Framework, and a rich library of UI factories and support classes.

Comment: On their site, under FAQ: "Can I use the project under java 1.4?

    No, as of 1.1.0 the codebase can only be run on 1.5+ JVM environments. "

Comment: not so much interested in rcp, I'm working on a legacy app. I see now that Spring 3.0 requires Java 5. Spring's web site is pretty, but not terribly informative.