# Dependency injection in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, dependency-injection

What options do I have to get annotation based dependency injection capabilities in a Java Swing based client application like as possible in JSF2 and EJB3?

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{myBean}")
private MyBean myBean;

public void setMyBean(MyBean myBean) {
    this.myBean= myBean;
}
```

or

```
@EJB
MyBean myBean;
```

Comment: [CDI can be used on Java SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575211/can-cdi-be-lessened-towards-jse).

Comment: yah, cdi is what im looking for. Funny how I've been messing around with jsf2/ejb3 for over a year and managed to completely miss CDI. Guess it boils down to which tutorial you look at when starting the journey and as long as it covers your needs, there is no reason to look further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from [CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575211/can-cdi-be-lessened-towards-jse) (see @BalusC's comment), you might want to have a look at
[Spring Rich Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273979/is-there-a-good-di-framework-suitable-for-java-1-4-and-se-swing-apps) and [Guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632033/how-to-use-guice-in-swing-application).

Answer (score 1):

Spring Rich Client is dead since 2009.